# "Go out into the world uncorrupted, a breath of fresh air"

Tags: past-participles

> Do everything readily and cheerfully—no bickering, no second-guessing allowed! **Go out into the world uncorrupted, a breath of fresh air in this squalid and polluted society.** 
> ([Philippians 2:14-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%202&version=MSG))

The second sentence seems to be an imperative. *Uncorrupted* and *a breath of fresh air* seem to be predicatives to the listeners, and the former the cause and the latter result. Is this right parsing?

Comment: I can see where the addition of a word would help eliminate the "problem" you are pointing out, as in: "Go out into the world uncorrupted, **as** a breath of fresh air..." or, "Go out into the world uncorrupted; **be** a breath of fresh air..." I find the construct as-is a little awkward, but not unacceptable from a grammatical point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing here is merely word-elision followed by a metaphor, used as a tool in order to improve the rhetoric of the sentence.

The two sentences are thus:

> Go out into the world uncorrupted! (imperative)
>
> Be a breath of fresh air in this squalid and polluted society! (metaphor).

These two sentences are combined with elision of "Be" into the sentence given.

Arguably the sentence could be more suitably punctuated with a semicolon instead of a comma joining and with an exclamation point at the end, however these are at the writers discretion.